# Как в sql запросе строку умножить на число?

Tags: sql, laravel

Вот сам запрос:

```
InfoUser::join('bets AS b','b.user','=','info_users.user_id')
            ->where([
                ['b.id_match','=',$request->id_match],
                ['b.name','=',$request->win]
            ])
            ->update(['info_users.balans' => 'b.summa'*$request->koof]);
```

В поле b.summa содержится число, но тип поля string. А переменная $request->koof содержит тоже число

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как же все таки умножить поле b.summa на $request->koof
Получается ошибка A non-numeric value encountered

Comment: Может ваш вариант это функции `CAST` или `CONVERT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InfoUser::join('bets AS b','b.user','=','info_users.user_id')
            ->where([
                ['b.id_match','=',$request->id_match],
                ['b.name','=',$request->win]
            ])
            ->update(['info_users.balans' => DB::raw('info_users.balans * '.$request->koof)]);
```